# Looking for a poem by Simon Armitage

Tags: poetry, identification-request, simon-armitage

I'm struggling to find a poem by Simon Armitage where he goes on a tour about him in disguise only to find that the tour guide doesn't know much about him. What was its name and what collection is it in?

Answer (score 4):

I've finally found it, the title is "Bringing It All Back Home" in the collection "Seeing Stars", it's the second from last piece there.